# How to index input words that has more than one word per line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The purpose of this code is to read through the sentences in `test.txt` and check if each word in `test_oov.txt` has an example sentence is `test.txt`

an example input file would be

```
joe biden is the us president
john mccain was a congressman
jpmorgan chase is the way to go
this is an irrelevant sentence
kanye west is an artist
```

and test_oov.txt would be

```
joe biden
john mccain
johns hopkins university
johnson johnson
jpmorgan chase
justice department
kamala harris
kanye west
```

and its supposed to output

```
joe biden : joe biden is the us president
john mccain : john mccain was a congressman
etc.
```

However, it does not work when the `test_oov.txt` input has more than one word per line. It works good when the word is just one word. However, when it's words like, `Joe Biden, or John mccain etc,` it doesn't work.

Code is below

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

# 1. create a reusable word index like {'worda': [2, 4, 10], 'wordb': [1, 9]}
with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as fp:
    news_sentences = sent_tokenize(fp.read())

index = {}
for i, sentence in enumerate(news_sentences):
    for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
        word = word.lower()
        if word not in index:
            index[word] = []
        index[word].append(i)

# 2. look up words from that index and retrieve the associated sentences
with open("test_oov.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as fp:
    oov_ner_data = [l.strip() for l in fp.readlines()]

matches = {}

for word in oov_ner_data:
    word = word.lower()
    if word in index:
        matches[word] = [news_sentences[i] for i in index[word]]

for (key, value) in matches.items():
    print(key + " : " + str(value))
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my homemade recipe.

```
dictEx = {names:sent for names in set([x.strip() for x in open('names.txt','r')]) for sent in [y.strip() for y in open('sentence.txt','r')] if names in sent}
```

output

```
{'joe biden': 'joe biden is the us president', 'john mccain': 'john mccain was a congressman', 'jpmorgan chase': 'jpmorgan chase is the way to go', 'kanye west': 'kanye west is an artist'}
```

---

Now what if in `names.txt` you had multiple names. The above code will take care of that.
But say you had multiple sentences in `sentence.txt`. Well that's a problem and the above code will not work for that. Instead you can try the following.

```
nameList = set([x.strip() for x in open('names.txt','r')])
sentences = [y.strip() for y in open('sentence.txt','r')]
dictEx = {}
for names in nameList:
    for sent in sentences:
        if names in sent and names in dictEx.keys():dictEx[names].append(sent)
        elif names in sent and names not in dictEx.keys():dictEx[names] = [sent]
print(dictEx)
```

Comment: What do you mean where do you put this?

Comment: I would consider changing `nameList` into a `set` instead of a `list`. That way, you don't have to worry about duplicates when reading in new values from `"names.txt"`. I would also consider using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) when looping over `sentences` like so: `dictEx.setdefault(names, []).append(sent)`. It would eliminate one additional lookup in your if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output every sentence that contains all the words in each search, you can build a dictionary that looks up the relevant strings, then narrow down to only those items that contain all the desired words.

```py
news_sentences = '''Joe Biden is the us president
John McCain was a congressman
JPMorgan Chase is the way to go
This is an irrelevant sentence
Kanye West IS an artist'''.split('\n')


from collections import defaultdict

newsDict = defaultdict(set)
for sentence in news_sentences:
    for word in sentence.split():
        newsDict[word.lower()].add(sentence)
#
oov_ner_data = input('test, hit me: ').split()

report = newsDict[oov_ner_data[0].lower()].copy()
for word in oov_ner_data[1:]:
    report &= newsDict[word.lower()]

if report:
    print(*report,sep='\n')
else:
    print("Good news")
```

There is some chance of "fake news" if the search words happen to occur in an irrelevant sentence. You can limit how much of each news sentence is scanned, but it seems to me that the key words could occur anywhere in principle. You could also potentially discard common words, both at news parsing and at input.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you need to import any library/module for this

```
import pprint # And ofcourse i import pprint just as i say that you dont need any importing, lol, this makes the printed dict look better in the terminal

matches = {}

# First store all the new sentences as a list
with open("test.txt", "r") as test:
    new_sentences = test.read().split("\n")
    # For checking without case sensitivity while also maintaining the original list
    new_sentences_lower = [item.lower() for item in new_sentences] 

# Second, store all the keys as a list
with open("test_oov.txt") as test_oov:
    stored_keys = test_oov.read().split("\n")
    # Again, to prevent case sensitivity and maintain original
    stored_keys_lower = [item.lower() for item in stored_keys]

# i and j are the indices of key and sentence respectively
for i, key in enumerate(stored_keys_lower):
    for j, sentence in enumerate(new_sentences_lower):
        if key in sentence: 
            matches.update({stored_keys[i]: new_sentences[j]})

pprint.pprint(matches)
```

If you expect more than one example sentence for each key, then itd be better to first make a dict with all the keys and the values as a list

That is before the for loop in the above code, you could do:

```
for key in stored_keys:
   matches.update({key: []})
```

This will return (by using pprint):

```
{'Joe biden': [],
 'john mccain': [],
 'johns hopkins university': [],
 'johnson johnson': [],
 'jpmorgan chase': [],
 'justice department': [],
 'kamala harris': [],
 'kanye west': []}
```

After this, a similar code to the one before, except we append the matching sentencing to the list:

```
for i, key in enumerate(stored_keys_lower):
    for j, sentence in enumerate(new_sentences_lower):
        if key in sentence: 
            matches[stored_keys[i]].append(new_sentences[j])

pprint.pprint(matches)
```

Final Output:

```
{'Joe biden': ['joe biden is the us president'],
 'john mccain': ['john mccain was a congressman'],
 'johns hopkins university': [],
 'johnson johnson': [],
 'jpmorgan chase': ['jpmorgan chase is the way to go'],
 'justice department': [],
 'kamala harris': [],
 'kanye west': ['kanye west is an artist']}
```